# Load only images using filename in the img tag alt attribute using AngularJS

Tags: image, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and trying to load only images from variety of files in my img tag.

Here I can get file names as ex1.jpg, ex2.png, ex3.txt, ex4.pdf etc. What I want to do is I will load the filename in my alt attribute of my img tag like

```
<img ng-src="http://localhost:9080/si-dev/binaryServlet?id=NDp3YXRlcjEuanBn" alt="ex1.jpg" ng-click="showPhoto1($index);" src="http://localhost:9080/si-dev/binaryServlet?id=NDp3YXRlcjEuanBn">
```

and also like

```
<img ng-src="http://localhost:9080/si-dev/binaryServlet?id=NDp3YXRlcjEuanBn" alt="ex3.txt" ng-click="showPhoto1($index);" src="http://localhost:9080/si-dev/binaryServlet?id=NDp3YXRlcjEuanBn">
```

I want load only images in my img tags using the filename extension in alt attribute.

If filename contains .jpg or .png only load the url into ng-src.

Is there anyway to do this in angular like ng-if etc?

Thanks

Comment: How do you get filenames?

Comment: You can achieve this using a custom directive. I can help you if you provide a plunkr